# Monotone functions from a measurable space to borel measure space

Tags: measure-theory

I try to solve next exercise

> $f: (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, where
>   $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space with just an
>   arbitrary measure and $\mathcal{B}$ is the borel sigma-algebra.
>
> Suppose $f$ is a monotone function.
>
> Then $f$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable if and only if
>   $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A}$.

My idea for ==>

Suppose $f$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable. We know $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\mathcal{O})$ because the borel sigma algebra is generated by the open sets. 
Then I use this lemma:

> Let $(X,A)$ and $(X', A')$ be measurable spaces and let $A'=\sigma(\mathcal{G'})$. Then
>   $T: X \to X'$ is $A/A'$-measurable if, and only if, $T^{-1}(\mathcal{G'})\subset A$,

So I know: $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}) \subset \mathcal{A}$. But $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O})$ is again an open set, because $f$ is a monotone function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?  But I don't know how I can now conclude $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A}$. So maybe somebody can help me with this step?

For <== I still don't have any idea, so maybe some of you can give me a hint.

Answer (score 1):

==> use that the identity map is a monotone function (inverse image of a set in B is again a set in B)
<== take monotone increasing function (for example). Borel sigma-algebra is generated by the sets $(a,\infty)$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}$. So the inverse of a monotone increasing function is empty, the whole real line or $(b,\infty)$ for $b\in \mathbb{R}$. They are all sets in the borel sigma-algebra, so also in $F$